# Why does C++ multiply this value by 4?

Tags: c++

- `pDosHeader` is loaded into `ECX`
- `pDosHeader->f_lfanew` is loaded into `EAX` (the value, not the pointer)

  ```
  pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)pDosHeader + (DWORD)pDosHeader->e_lfanew);
  ```

The above code ades `ECX + EAX` and gets me the desired result... but apparently it's bad habbit to cast pointers to DWORD's if I decide to compile something on x64

1. `pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)( (PDWORD)pDosHeader + (DWORD)pDosHeader->e_lfanew );`
2. `pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)( (PDWORD)pDosHeader + pDosHeader->e_lfanew );`

The above code adds `ECX + EAX * 4` and gets me a result that I do not desire. for both 1 and 2.

My question is why? Why does C++ compile my code like this? Why does it multiply e_lfanew by 4 when I cast the dos header into a pointer?

Does it assume that I want to make my pointer point to the next element x number of times? Therefore multiplying it by 4 so that I can get to the e_lfanew(th) element instead of adding e_lfanew?  It probably does.

So what do I do?  What is the correct way of casting this code the C++ way so it gets the desired result while not using bad habits?

I don't want the `e_lfanewth` element of `pDosHeader`.  I just want it to add `e_lfanew` to `pDosHeader`.

Comment: Basic pointer arithmetic. If you don't recognize it, you should read a good beginner book or tutorial on C++, especially with regards to pointers.

Comment: The correct way to solve this is to use [`offsetof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz4y9b9a.aspx). Let the compiler do the hard work.

Comment: As I stated in my question.  I'm aware of this.  I'm technically asking what is the C++ way of doing this, because you are not supposed to cast pointers to DWORD's because it's a bad habit for x64.

Comment: Lose the Microsoft typedefs for a start! Then all will become clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does it multiply e_lfanew by 4 when I cast the dos header into a pointer?

Because this is how pointer arithmetic works in both C and C++. When you add an integer to a pointer, the pointer is adjusted by the given number of *elements*, not *bytes*. Since `PDWORD` points to `DWORD` and `DWORD` is four bytes wide, adding `n` to it adds `4 * n` to the address.

To make it work the way you want, change the pointer to `PBYTE`.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a number to a pointer of type T, the pointer will increase by number*sizeof(T).

This should do what you want:

```
pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)( (char*)pDosHeader + pDosHeader->e_lfanew );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add an integer `i` to a pointer `p` as in `p + i`, this takes into account the size of the type of `*p`. For example, if `p` was a pointer to an `int`, and `sizeof(int)` was 4, then `p+1` would be 4 bytes beyond `p`. (This is assuming that you are pointing to memory that you are allowed to point to, otherwise it is undefined.) Thus `p[1]` and `*(p+1)` are equivalent expressions.

To add an absolute number of bytes to a pointer, it must be a multiple of the size of the type being pointed to and you must convert it to a number of objects being pointed to. For example, for `int *ip` being incremented by a number of bytes `int offset`:

```
ip = ip + offset / sizeof(*ip);
```

This requires offset to be a multiple of `sizeof(int)`.

This seems not the case in your problem though, if `pDosHeader->e_lfanew` is an arbitrary number of bytes. In this case use Master T's or NPE's solution, with a cast of the pointer to a `char *`. Normally casting between pointers to different types would be undefined behaviour, but there is an exception for `char *` under the aliasing rules, so that would work regardless of the type of `pDosHeader`.

Comment: Your arithmetic is all wrong. You are applying the scaling at the wrong end, producing the wrong result. Compare your solution to that posted by [Master T](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20892127/1889329) and you'll see what is wrong.

Comment: Please explain. The only difference I can see is that Master T's answer will work if pDosHeader->e_lfanew is not a multiple of sizeof(*pDosHeader), and that case is probably undefined behaviour anyway (think increasing an int pointer by 3 bytes).

Comment: The only difference is precisely the problem here. `e_lfanew` is a **byte** offset into a file. Since `e_lfanew` is stored in that file you cannot place any restrictions on it either.

Comment: I did not consider the meaning of `e_lfanew` or `pDosHeader`. Whether Master T's solution will work/is safe depends on what `pDosHeader` points to. In the context of reading Windows executable files it may be valid.

Comment: Upon further research it seems that casting to `char *` is always valid.